# How to remove tags from a string in python using regular expressions? (NOT in HTML)

Tags: python, strip, arcmap

I need to remove tags from a string in python.

```
<FNT name="Century Schoolbook" size="22">Title</FNT>
```

What is the most efficient way to remove the entire tag on both ends, leaving only "Title"? I've only seen ways to do this with HTML tags, and that hasn't worked for me in python. I'm using this particularly for ArcMap, a GIS program. It has it's own tags for its layout elements, and I just need to remove the tags for two specific title text elements. I believe regular expressions should work fine for this, but I'm open to any other suggestions.

Comment: do you want <FNT name="Century Schoolbook" size="22">Title</FNT> to be <FNT>Title</FNT> when done,  or Title or <>Title<> or ? , not sure from your question what you are after ?

Comment: So what should this string look like after processing?  I'm not entirely clear on what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry. The string should be "Title" after processing.

Comment: As a sibling of html, xml is no more regular or context-free than html. I'm not sure the entire scope of your situation, but at a quick glance, regular expressions still look like the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This should work:

```
import re
re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', mystring)
```

**To everyone saying that regexes are not the correct tool for the job:**

The context of the problem is such that all the objections regarding regular/context-free languages are invalid. His language essentially consists of three entities: `a = <`, `b = >`, and `c = [^><]+`. He wants to remove any occurrences of `acb`. This fairly directly characterizes his problem as one involving a context-free grammar, and it is not much harder to characterize it as a regular one.

I know everyone likes the "you can't parse HTML with regular expressions" answer, but the OP doesn't want to parse it, he just wants to perform a simple transformation.

Comment: This didn't work. It returned the original string. Thanks though

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the all-important `*` character. Try again?

Answer (score 6):

Please avoid using regex. Eventhough regex will work on your simple string, but you'd get problem in the future if you get a complex one.

You can use BeautifulSoup `get_text()` feature.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '<FNT name="Century Schoolbook" size="22">Title</FNT>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

print(soup.get_text())
```

Answer (score 3):

Searching this regex and replacing it with an empty string should work.

```
/<[A-Za-z\/][^>]*>/
```

Example (from python shell):

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string = '<FNT name="Century Schoolbook" size="22">Title</FNT>'
>>> print re.sub('<[A-Za-z\/][^>]*>', '', my_string)
Title
```

Comment: That didn't work either. Could you give me an example of how you would search and replace using this? I tried, and it returned the original string.

Comment: Added an example. Did you forget `import re`?

Answer (score 1):

If it's only for parsing and retrieving value, you might take a look at BeautifulStoneSoup.

Answer (score 1):

If the source text is well-formed XML, you can use the stdlib module [ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
mystring = """<FNT name="Century Schoolbook" size="22">Title</FNT>"""
element = ET.XML(mystring)
print element.text  # 'Title'
```

If the source isn't well-formed, BeautifulSoup is a good suggestion. Using regular expressions to parse tags is not a good idea, as several posters have pointed out.

Comment: If FNT would contain another tag in the middle of "Title", only the part up to the inner tag will be printed.

Answer (score -3):

Use an XML parser, such as ElementTree.  Regular expressions are not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Unless the input is not guaranteed to be well-formed XML, in which case regex is arguably the _only_ reasonable tool for the job. I'm also willing to bet that regex will perform significantly faster than handling the string as an XML document.

Comment: If the input is not well-formed XML, then implementing a full parser would be the proper way to do this.  The grammar is complex enough that regular expressions are not enough.