# Python strip XML tags from document

Tags: python, xml, regex

I am trying to strip XML tags from a document using Python, a language I am a novice in. Here is my first attempt using regex, whixh was really a hope-for-the-best idea.

```
mfile = file("somefile.xml","w")

for line in mfile:
    re.sub('<./>',"",line) #trying to match elements between < and />
```

That failed miserably. I would like to know how it should be done with regex.

Secondly, I googled and found: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440481-strips-xmlhtml-tags-from-string/

which seems to work. But I would like to know is there a simpler way to get rid of all xml tags? Maybe using ElementTree?

Comment: Opening the file with option `"w"` will start with an empty file and your iterating over it is useless.

Comment: The best way is to use a parser, such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). The second answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python) will help. (You want to use `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup` and use BeautifulStoneSoup in the parsing instead).

Comment: You can't parse [X]HTML with [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: To be clear- are you trying to change the document in place, or write it to a new document?

Comment: @David Robinson. For the above example I was trying to change it in place. I was then going to modify it to create a new document

Comment: You merely forgot the repetition indicator. `'<.*/>'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove tags from a string in python using regular expressions? (NOT in HTML)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662142/how-to-remove-tags-from-a-string-in-python-using-regular-expressions-not-in-ht)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please, note, that usually it is not normal to do it by regular expressions. See [Jeremiah answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12824035/284947).

Try this:

```
import re

text = re.sub('<[^<]+>', "", open("/path/to/file").read())
with open("/path/to/file", "w") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Comment: @JJG: Note that you'd still need something after the for loop (this doesn't change the file on its own

Comment: @David Robinson Thanks I realize that now

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the regex there. It seems to match the start < and then not match another < before matching the final >.

Comment: @JJG, 1. char "<" (`\<`), then one or more chars are not "<" (`[^\<]+`), and char ">" (`\>`)

Comment: The problem is that the regular expression will always return the most subsequence. So we have to ensure that between "<" and ">" will not be any other tags.

Comment: @defuz Nicely explained. Thank you

Answer (score 25):

The most reliable way to do this is probably with [LXML](http://lxml.de/api.html).

```
from lxml import etree
...
tree = etree.parse('somefile.xml')
notags = etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf8', method='text')
print(notags)
```

It will avoid the problems with "parsing" XML with regular expressions, and should correctly handle escaping and everything.

Comment: Or if you know the string, instead of loading from a file you can `tree=etree.fromstring(xml_string)`, also notags ends up as *bytes* so you might want to do a `.decode('utf-8')` to it to get a *string*.

Answer (score 16):

An alternative to Jeremiah's answer without requiring the lxml external library:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
...
tree = ET.fromstring(Text)
notags = ET.tostring(tree, encoding='utf8', method='text')
print(notags)
```

Should work with any Python >= 2.5

Comment: It gives error AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'itertext'

Comment: @MajesticRa This is strange, maybe you can try to use another method than 'text'? Are you using Python3 maybe? This would explain the change, maybe the name for this method changed.