# How to ignore annotation characters on SyntaxNet?

Tags: syntaxnet

I want to ignore annotation characters when parsing text on syntaxnet.

For example, in the case below, I want to ignore `<X>` and `</X>` annotation characters.

```
<PERSON>Michael Jordan</PERSON> is a professor at <LOC>Berkeley</LOC>.
```

So, I expect next output.

```
_    <PERSON>    _     ...
1    Michael     _     ...
2    Jordan      _     ...
_    </PERSON>   _     ...
3    is          _     ...
...
```

Isn't SyntaxNet has such kind of features?

Answer (score 0):

No, SyntaxNet does not have specific features to manipulate xml tags.  However you can preprocess your data easily in Python with something like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(
    "<DOC><PERSON>Michael Jordan</PERSON> is a "
    "professor at <LOC>Berkeley</LOC>.</DOC>")
notags = ET.tostring(tree, encoding='utf8', method='text')
print(notags)
```

See also [Python strip XML tags from document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823568/python-strip-xml-tags-from-document/12824035#12824035).

Comment: Thanks. But I think if remove XML tags from text, it is hard to merge SyntaxNet outpust and XML tags. I want to use SyntaxNet outputs and XML annotation information to another machine learning's feature.