# How do I manually strip XML tags?

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove the tags and create a new file but I can't see at how to accomplish this. I'm giving a file that has XML tags and I want to use strip and split to make into a list/string. I can't use an XML parser, or any other libraries.

here is the text file:

```
<team> <name>Denver Broncos</name> <players> <player> <jno>50</jno> <fname>Zaire</fname> <lname>Anderson</lname> <height>5-11</height> <weight>220</weight> <age>24</age> <position>ILB</position> <school>Nebraska</school> </player> <player> <jno>48</jno> <fname>Shaquil</fname> <lname>Barrett</lname> <height>6-2</height> <weight>250</weight> <age>23</age> <position>OLB</position> <school>Colorado State</school> </player> <player> <jno>35</jno> <fname>Kapri</fname> <lname>Bibbs</lname> <height>5-11</height> <weight>203</weight> <age>23</age> <position>RB</position> <school>Colorado State</school> </player> </players> </team>
```

I want to use the string/list to produce a sentence like the following below:

> Here  is  the roster  for the Denver  Broncos.  There are 3
>   players   on  the team.       Zaire   Anderson,   ILB,    wears   #50.        He  is  5 foot  11
>   inches    tall,   and weighs  220 pounds.     He  is  24
>   years old.        He  went    to  Nebraska.   Shaquil Barrett,    OLB,    wears   #48.        He  is  6
>   foot  2 inches    tall,   and weighs  250 pounds.     He  is  23
>   years old.        He  went    to  Colorado    State.      Kapri   Bibbs,  RB, wears   #48.        He  is  5
>   foot  11 inches   tall,   and weighs  203 pounds.     He  is  23
>   years old.        He  went    to  Colorado    State.

```
def test(filename):
    f=open(filename,"r")
    line = f.readline()
    f2 = open("BearsRoster.txt", "w")
    print line
    myList = []
    stringl = ""
    for i in line:
        if i == ("<"):
            while i != ">":
                line.remove(i)


        else:


            stringl = stringl + i
            myList.append(stringl)
            stringl = ""
        else:
            stringl = stringl + i
    print myList
    for i in myList:
        print i
        print myList

        if i[0] == "<" or " ":
            myList.remove(i)
```

obviously this code is incorrect.  My idea was to go through the string and try to strip `<xxxxx>` that code.  I just don't know how to approach it.  After that I want to put that into the sentence I posted.

Comment: [Have you tried  using an XML parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: you cannot import libraries. thus cannot use a xml parser

Comment: Do the answers from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823568/python-strip-xml-tags-from-document) help?

Comment: when you find `<` then set `skip=True` and when you find `>` then set `skip=False` and then use `skip` to copy char to new list. At the end concatenate all chars in new string.

Comment: cannot import @af3ld

Comment: Why not? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @imaqtpie - why can't you import libraries? Is this a personal challenge or business requirement? Understand `import` is simply looking to other .py scripts. Treating xml like txt will break hearts among xml gurus!

Answer (score 0):

To remove tags use variable `skip=True/False` to control when to copy char to new string.

When you find `<` then set `skip=True`, when you find `>` then set `skip=False`

```
data = '''<team> <name>Denver Broncos</name> <players> <player> <jno>50</jno> <fname>Zaire</fname> <lname>Anderson</lname> <height>5-11</height> <weight>220</weight> <age>24</age> <position>ILB</position> <school>Nebraska</school> </player> <player> <jno>48</jno> <fname>Shaquil</fname> <lname>Barrett</lname> <height>6-2</height> <weight>250</weight> <age>23</age> <position>OLB</position> <school>Colorado State</school> </player> <player> <jno>35</jno> <fname>Kapri</fname> <lname>Bibbs</lname> <height>5-11</height> <weight>203</weight> <age>23</age> <position>RB</position> <school>Colorado State</school> </player> </players> </team>'''

skip = False
result = ''

for char in data:
    if char == '<':
        skip = True
    elif char == '>':
        skip = False
    elif not skip:
        result += char

print(result)
```

If you need data from tags then you will have to build parser - recognize opening and closing tags, remember tags name, and probably build tree with tags. So you need a lot more work.