# python html strip of hyperlinked text only

Tags: python, html, strip

So I have trying to remove the HTML from

```
<a href="/define.php?term=dubstep&defid=5175360">dubstep</a> the music that is created from transformers having s$#
```

So it reads like so after parsed

> dubstep - the music that is created from transformers having S$#

I want to extract the text `dubstep` from this html hyperlink

how would I go about doing this?

I read the solution over here
[How to remove tags from a string in python using regular expressions? (NOT in HTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662142/how-to-remove-tags-from-a-string-in-python-using-regular-expressions-not-in-ht)

but i get

```
<class 'NameError'>, NameError("name 're' is not defined",), <traceback object at 0x036A41E8>)
```

Comment: Did you import `re` module using `import re`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `BeautifulSoup`?

```
In [44]: from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

In [45]: soup = BeautifulSoup ('''<a href="/define.php?term=dubstep&defid=5175360">dubstep</a> the music that is created from transformers having s$#''')

In [46]: soup.find('a').text
Out[46]: u'dubstep'
```

EDIT:

Or if you just want text:

```
In [48]: soup.text 
Out[48]: u'dubstep the music that is created from transformers having s$#'
```

Answer (score 0):

well

```
 NameError("name 're' is not defined",),
```

means you forgot to `import re` at the beginning, but this is a guess.

also, since you only need the word between the `<a></a>` tags, you need a regexp similar to this:

```
 .*<a .*>([^<]*)</a>.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
html = <a href="/define.php?term=dubstep&defid=5175360">dubstep</a> the music that is created from transformers having s$#
soup = Beautifulsoup(html)
print(soup.get_text())
```